# py2app setup.py usage question

Tags: python, py2app

Ok so I'm trying to use py2app to generate a distribution for my project. I'm still not sure I get the hang of it tho. So my setup.py looks like this:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup
import setuptools

PACKAGES = ['sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite']
MODULES = ['sqlite3']

APP = ['tvb/interfaces/web/run.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'packages': PACKAGES ,
           'includes' : MODULES }
DATA_FILES = []

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    packages = setuptools.find_packages(), 
    include_package_data=True,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app', "pyopengl", "cherrypy", "sqlalchemy", "simplejson", 
                          "formencode", "genshi", "quantities","numpy", "scipy",
                          "numexpr", "nibabel", "cfflib", "mdp", "apscheduler",
                          "scikits.learn"]
)
```

So my first question would be: What should I include in my MODULES for py2app here? Does py2app know to scan for the things in setup_requires and include them or do I need to add some entries for them in MODULES ?

Another problem is that I'm getting an: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine dialect for 'sqlite'` when trying to run my app. After lots of googling I only saw that for py2exe you need to include the `sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite` as a package but it doesn't seem to work for me. Am I missing something here?

The last one is that I'm getting a: `malformed object (load command 3 cmdsize not a multiple of 8)` just before the `python setup.py py2app`. Is this normal?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well seems I got the whole thing wrong.

```
'includes' : ['sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite']
```

Instead of packages, and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Could you post your final setup.py? I'm using SQLAlchemy the same, but with mysql and I haven't figured out what exactly goes where to fix the dialect error.

Answer (score 0):

```
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['your_prog.py']
DATA_FILES = ['your.db']
OPTIONS = {
'includes' : ['sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite',"os", "platform"]
}
setup(
app=APP,
data_files=DATA_FILES,
options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

This is the sample setup.py for the .py progs that includes sqlite database file. This is the sample setup.py file for beginers.
if your.db in same directory of your_prog.py you can use this configuration. Macos app will work normally as it is. If do not  specify the .db file, app will work but couldn't connect to database file.

Comment: This is the sample setup.py for the .py progs that includes sqlite database file.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**