# Py2app does not include the Sqlite driver- "Database error: Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

Tags: sqlite, py2app

I am having the same issue described in [this post on the py2app mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2009-January/020930.html).

I have a python application that uses a sqlite database.  On my machine, which has all the dependencies installed, there are no issues.  However, when I bundle the application with py2app, clicking a menu that causes the database to be accessed results in this error:

> Database error: Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

For the Windows installer, the files in  `\Qt\version\plugins\sqldrivers\*.*` can be copied to `\myApp\sqldrivers\*`

The same files on the Mac can be found in　`/opt/local/share/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers` (installed via Macports).

However, copying the `sqldrivers` directory to my application's `Resources` or `Frameworks` directories still results in the same error.

How can I add sqlite support into my application that is built using py2app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the pyside recipe does have a way to specify which qt-plugins you need...

```
    options=dict(py2app={
                         'argv_emulation': True,
                         'qt_plugins' : "sqldrivers",
                         }
                 ),
```

This puts all the sqldrivers into the right directory and setups qt.conf correctly.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried what he said
in this post ?
[py2app setup.py usage question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270554/py2app-setup-py-usage-question)
it mentioned

> you need to include the sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite as a package

Comment: I'm not using sqlalchemy so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work as follows:

After building with py2app, inside the application's Contents directory, make a new `plugins` directory.

Then copy sqldrivers/libqsqlite.dylib into this plugins directory.

Afterwards, install_name_tool has to be used to change the library links in libqsqlite.dylib to point to the Qt libraries in the application's Frameworks directory rather than the system Qt libraries.